# I want to create space on both sides of my webpage without CSS

Tags: html

I am currently making a simple website with only HTML to work with, and want to make some space on the sides, [literally like this page I'm on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv9FH.jpg)

Is there any way to do this only with html tags?

## Edit

Thanks for all the responses guys, there's one thing I want to clarify, the website I'm working on is a school project, we don't learn about css in classes, so we don't get marks from using it.

So after some failed trials, I figured out I can do it under the `<style>` tag, using inclusively `padding-left` and `padding-right`, the code is like this: 
`<body style="padding:50px; padding-left:450px; padding-right:450px">`

Comment: Why without CSS? What's the reason for this requirement? Seems a bit silly to attempt to do what amounts to **styling** without Cascading **Style** Sheets.

Comment: I haven't seen something like this done without CSS so i'd be interested in seeing the answer.

Comment: This page that you're on uses CSS to make the space you are seeing...

Comment: Maybe you want to do it "without css"  because you don't know css? if that is the case - read a tutorial. Your question doesn't make any sense

Comment: If by css you mean using an external stylesheet, than feel free to use inline css or the style tags. Even with divs used as margin, you'll end up setting css widths.

Comment: If you mean without *external* CSS then yeah, you could use `style` tags on your HTML document or *inline* CSS... but still, you *need* CSS to achieve what you want

Comment: @Reez0 take a look at my answer `;-)`

Comment: To the nay-sayers; This question makes perfect sense, it is absolutely **not best practise**, and it's absolutely **not a professional approach to HTML content  layout**, but it is not a nonsense question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with **shudders** HTML layout tables in **shudders** HTML4.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>HTML4 Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      </head>
      <body>
        <table align='center' width='33%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='1'>
          <tr>
           <td>Website contents goes in here<Br><Br><BR>
               Website contents goes in here<Br><Br>
               Website contents goes in here<Br><Br>
               Website contents goes in here<Br><Br>
               Website contents goes in here<Br><Br></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
     
      </body>
    </html>
```

Create a `<table>` element with a percentage width and `align=center` attributes and this should display as you wish.

( `border='1'` is purely for illustrating the table-contents workspace on the page; it should be `border='0'` ).

> *P.S Now I feel dirty. I need a shower and a nice HTML5 CSS page to play on until I feel better. Maybe I should start a Patreon page?.*